How is convenience sampling used in healthcare-associated infections prevalence studies?
Question
Examples of such studies:

Prevalence, Antimicrobial Drug Resistance and Associated Risk Factors of Streptococcus Pneumoniae Bacteria Infection Among
Under-Five Children With Acute Lower Respiratory Tract Infection
Attending Sheik Hassan Yebere Referral Hospital, Jig-Jiga, Ethiopia:
"The study was conducted at Sheik Hassan Yebere Referral Hospital from
March 1 to April 30, 2021. ...... Then, from pediatric outpatient
department study participants who had symptoms of acute lower
respiratory tract infection were selected by using convenience
sampling method."
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10243350/


Multidrug-resistant among Non-Fermenting Gram-negative Bacteria Isolated in the Department of Microbiology of a Tertiary Care
Centre:
A descriptive cross-sectional study was conducted in the Department of
Microbiology of a tertiary care centre from 1 September 2021 to 30
August 2022 after obtaining ethical approval from the Institutional
Review Committee. All samples received in the Microbiology laboratory
for diagnostic purposes were included. A convenience sampling method
was used.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10725231/


Positive Bacterial Culture among Adults with Suspected Urinary Tract Infections Presenting to the Department of Medicine of a Tertiary Care
Centre:
"Data was collected between 1 July 2022 to 31 December 2022...... A
convenience sampling method was used."
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10924528/

Self-investigation
What I understand so far:
In such studies, the population consists of all patients present in the study hospital or department throughout the study duration. However, there is a barrier to accessing the entire population due to the factor of time. That's why convenience sampling method is used.
How does the consideration that some of the population might not be available during sample selection, but could become available later during the sampling process, come into play?
What role does the sample size play, particularly if the calculated sample size is, say, 200 patients? These studies mention a "minimum sample size". Could this be considered in part sequential sampling, even if the studies don’t explicitly mention it?
So the overall method is to be "Convenience sequential sampling".
Disclaimer: I have been searching for two weeks for an answer.

It's up to the individual studies to report their sampling methods and criteria for stopping or other justification of the time frame used. If they haven't, that's their fault and the fault of peer reviewers to have not caught what is missing.

We are not talking about one or even the three studies mentioned here, there are a bunch of these. They could be onto something, even if they didn't mention it. Maybe they just know it.

What do you mean "they could be onto something"?

Their studies could be statistically valid for the research purpose.

What would make them statistically valid and what would make them statistically invalid? If the methods are not clear, how could someone tell?

I'm not after certain studies per se, but a type of studies which the three studies mentioned belong to, labeled by the research purpose and "Convenience  sampling", even if they didn't describe their methodology fully. Maybe they didn't mention the full statistical methods, there could some other study that did mention the full method. Also, from the research purpose, it should be possible to guess at-least not the exact method they used, but the possible one(s).

I'll reiterate my first comment: "It's up to the individual studies to report their sampling methods and criteria for stopping or other justification of the time frame used. If they haven't, that's their fault and the fault of peer reviewers to have not caught what is missing." - you can't fix what they haven't included by asking third parties here.
